# Use macbook as remote touchpad / keyboard

Tags: remote-desktop, remote-access, remote-control

I own a macbook, and am planning on purchasing a [pc desktop which comes with no keyboard or mouse](http://www.dell.com/us/p/alienware-x51/pd).  I'll be hooking this pc up to my living room television.

What I would love to be able to do is to sit on my couch with my laptop and use it, effectively, as a wireless keyboard / mouse.

Thought about the following possibilities:

1. Remoting - most (all?) solutions allow my macbook to control my PC, but not to see that control on the screen.
2. Bluetooth - perhaps I can 'expose' my macbook's keyboard and trackpad as bluetooth devices, but there doesn't seem to be a way to do that.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually ended up using TeamViewer, which has been working great.

Answer (score 3):

Use synergy utility. On Mac you have nice GUI for it called QuickSynergy. You can find both on sourceforge (though newer version of QuickSynergy might be on GoogleCode, I'm not sure).

The utility allows you to use your keyboard and mouse to control remote machine. It has versions for Mac OS and Windows that work with each other. It has GUI for Windows, and QuickSynergy utility provides GUI under Mac OS

Comment: Please elaborate on why this solves the problem

Answer (score 2):

Consider trying out [Synergy](http://synergy-foss.org/fi/).

Comment: Please elaborate on why this solves the problem

Comment: question was: "What I would love to be able to do is to sit on my couch with my laptop and use it, effectively, as a wireless keyboard / mouse.". Synergy is, essentially, a software KVM. It allows just this.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft's [Remote Desktop Connection](https://www.microsoft.com/mac/remote-desktop-client) for the Mac lets you both see and control your PC.  I used to run the machines side-by-side but it would have worked just as well to remote across the planet.